# React-admin pagination with DynamoDB lastEvaluatedKey - pagination

Tags: express, amazon-dynamodb, react-admin

I`m using react-admin to build CMS for my site. On my Express backend I`m intercepting the call from the react admin and querying the DynamoDB table. I want to use InfiniteList to get the results of DynamoDB. The issue is that DynamoDB paginates the results and therefore I`m receiving them on chunks with lastEvaluatedKey in case of more results. How can I pass this lastEvaluatedKey to react-admin and how react-admin can return the lastEvaluatedKey so I can query the DynamoDB table once again with new InputCommands where I include the ExclusiveStartKey as per the AWS documentation. My dataProvider is simpleRestProvider.

I`ve tried to follow the documentation here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useInfiniteGetList.html#options but this does not help me.